# Questions about some math symbols.

Tags: geometry

Given two vectors $\omega_1,\omega_2$, and two points $p_1,p_2$, I have following questions:

Does $\|\omega_1\|$ means normalize the vector $\omega_1$ ?

What is the meaning of $\|\omega_1\|_2$, I saw this subscript $2$ in some paper.

If I want to normalize $(p_1-p_2)$ first and dot with $\omega_1$, is this correct: $\|(p_1-p_2)\| \cdot \omega_1$.

If I don't want normalization term, is this correct: $(p_1-p_2) \cdot \omega_1$.

It looks like $\overline{p_1p_2}$ have the same meaning of $(p_1-p_2)$, $\overline{p_1p_2}$ is used in the text of article and $(p_1-p_2)$ is used in the equation. I'm not sure if I got this right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider editing your question with more context about where you came across this notation to make it easier to answer in your specific circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to be 100% sure without knowing the source since notation often varies from text to text, but the symbols you mention have meanings which are almost universally accepted and so I will detail these meanings.

$\lVert\cdot\rVert$ typically denotes a *norm* on a vector space, which in particular is a function $V\to\mathbb{R}$. If $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, then if no qualification is given, this will likely be the Euclidean norm $$\lVert(x_1,\dots,x_n)\rVert=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}.$$ Once a norm is defined, this can be used to *normalise* vectors, for example of $\omega_1$ is a non-zero vector, its normalisation is $\omega_1/\lVert\omega_1\rVert$.

There are many different choices of norms for a vector space, and some of the most common have special names, in particular the so-called [$p$-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) are typically denoted $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$, so $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ denotes the $2$-norm, which is just the same as the Euclidean norm above.

Since the norm of a vector is a real number, it does not make sense to take the dot product of a vector and the norm of another vector like $\lVert(p_1-p_2\rVert\cdot\omega_1$. Similarly note that the dot product of two vectors is a real number, not a vector, so $(p_1-p_2)\cdot\omega_1$ is not a vector and may not be what you are after in this context.

The use of the overline notation often means the complex conjugate of a vector in a complex vector space. I cannot say more without knowing the context of where you can across the notation. I hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$||\omega||$ means the norm of $\omega$ according to the normed vector space that you’re in.

Assuming you have an inner product defined, $(p_1-p_2)\cdot \omega$ is correct. However you can’t take the inner product of a real number and a vector (unless you’re in $\mathbb{R}$) so if you choose to norm  $p_1-p_2$ it would just be  $||p_1-p_2|| \omega$.

$\overline{p_1p_2}$ is the vector which starts at $p_1$ and ends at $p_2$ so it would seem more logical if it is equal to $p_2-p_1$ because then $p_1+\overline{p_1p_2}=p_1+(p_2-p_1)=p_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.